# Spring bean post processor: inject a value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a BeanPostProcessor bean and I want to inject two string variables with values from application.properties file. However, they are not getting injected and left with a placeholder's value.

```
@Component
public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Value("${property1}")
    private String property1;

    @Value("${property2}")
    private String property2;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        ...
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
       ...
       return bean;
    }
}
```

In both method values of the variables are `${property1}` and `${property2}`.
I've tried injecting them in a regular bean and it works fine, so it definitely has to do something with the bean being BeanPostProcessor.
Is there a way to inject values somehow? I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.0.

Comment: Have you tried injecting them into _another_ class, and then make that class a dependency of the `BeanPostProcessor`?  It could be that spring's creating the bean post processor _before_ whatever it is which is retrieving the `@Value`.

Comment: Just tried it, the values are still populated with placeholders. However, there's a workaround - I made a @ConfigurationProperties bean for these props and it's autowiring to the bpp bean with already filled values. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's intended. See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) for `@Value`:

> Note that actual processing of the @Value annotation is performed by a BeanPostProcessor which in turn means that you cannot use @Value within BeanPostProcessor or BeanFactoryPostProcessor types. Please consult the javadoc for the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor class (which, by default, checks for the presence of this annotation).

As a workaround, you can, for example, create your post processor as bean manually inside a class marked as `@Configuration` and pass this value from there as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I've also suggested a workaround in the question's comments.

Comment: Yes, with `@ConfigurationProperties` instead of `@Value` it is also possible (and, in my opinion, more elegant)

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't work. Property values are still `null`. What works is this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27813297/58962